# how to delay google crawling until page is ready

Tags: jquery, seo, google-search

I know this is up to google, but since the web has evolved then I thought there might be something out there.

Here is the issue.

I have a `jQuery.ajax({})` on `jQuery.ready(...)` once the page has loaded then I populate the contents using some json data.

I just thought there could be a parameter to let google know when they crawl there is an ajax request that populates the contents of the page.

The reason... SEO I need a better chance than having a `please wait...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most crawlers  do not interpret JavaScript. I do no know for sure whether or not Google have a reasonable support for it, but i suppose that if they support any JS at all, it would be very limited. Thus loading your main content with AJAX is inherently a bad idea.

Instead you should print out most or all content into the HTML before you send it to the browser.

**Edited**
My solution ... just as easy (on PHP)

```
<?php $cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[USERNAME]/uploads/?v=2&alt=json')); ?>
```

Comment: I have edited your question if you don't mind but you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the benefit of loading the main content via javascript?

Delayed loading like this is sometimes done for perceived speed. But you do it for secondary content so the main content loads first.

It's also sometimes used to make one page dynamic and load multiple pages of content without reloading. There is a benefit here. In this case I feel the best structure is "progressive enhancement". Develop your website using basic html links and loading, then add JavaScript on top to make it dynamically load and create an enhanced experience. Then crawlers still see the content and users get the cooler/faster experience.

Answer (score 0):

see this. the robots.txt is the most commonly used method.

```
http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing
```

Comment: He wants robots to search the page.  However, he wants them to "wait" until the page is fully loaded via javascript.  Which aint going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If all your content is retrieved via ajax, then you need to use the hashbang url approach to redirect crawlers to a place where you serve html snapshots of your loaded content. Here is a good website for learning the details of this approach:
http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/
And a message from google:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

Essentially, when you go to a page with a hashbang( !# ) fragment in the url, google et al. will know to redirect to another page to find a snapshot of the html content to index. So a url like:
http://url.com/ajax/#!ajax-crawling-scheme

will redirect a crawler to:
http://url.com/ajax?_escaped_fragment_=ajax-crawling-scheme

At this location you will serve the html snapshot you'd like indexed (this can be generated on the fly by the server using a headless browser and returning the page's state after ajax is loaded, or just having static dumps of these pages).

Here is a service (I am not affiliated, nor have I used it) that serves these snapshots for you, though you have to set up the hashbang urls and routing I believe:

https://ajaxsnapshots.com/

Comment: http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch Hashbangs should not be used. this was a very old idea, that went horribly wrong.

Comment: Well this seems like opinion to me. If you need google to index your ajax content, then either you configure your server to display the proper state of the application on direct request and use pushState to  change the url most of the time (which seems like double work), or you use hashbang urls. Sometimes it will also work to just add the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag instead of using hashbang urls. No matter what you need to configure your server to catch the _escaped_fragment paramater and serve static content to the crawlers.